# Sum in C cannot solve

Tags: c, sum

Ok,so I wrote this program and compiled it. It's everything ok, but when I run it in windows 7 it get's me an error c0000005. I have no idea why.

### Overview of my program

I want this program to give me the sum of this numbers depends of an given "n" : 1-1x3+1x3x5-...+-1x3x5x...x(2*n-1).

Please help me,I am a begginer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
  int n, sum=0, i, signum;
  printf("Give n: ");
  scanf("%d", n);
  for(i=1, signum=1; i-(2*n-1); sum+=(signum*(sum*i)),i+2,signum=-signum)
    ;
  printf("Sum is: %d", sum);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to change `i+2` to `i+=2`

Comment: a simple suggestion avoid writting 2 instructions in the same line, or your teachers are going to hate you

Comment: Did "error c0000005" come with some words?

Comment: I tried to change i+2 with i+=2 but it gives me the same error. And my teacher put me to write the for loop in this way, it's driving me crazy :(

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: suma test.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 53ad4595
  Fault Module Name: msvcrt.dll
  Fault Module Version: 7.0.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4a5bda6f
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0001ecc0
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: Have you ever tried with debugger?

Comment: I have no idea how to use debugger...if you can help me...

Comment: @haccks There is no UB. There is sequence point between each comma.

Comment: @user694733; Deleting my comment :)

Comment: @panti93 'I have no idea how to use debugger' - make finding this out your very next task, before you ever write another line of code.  If you cannot debug, you cannot write programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the code like this, which I think is a lot clearer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n, sum = 1, term = 1;
    printf("Give n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);             // address of n
    for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {   // simple for loop
        term *= -(2 * i - 1);    // multiply by previous and flip sign
        sum += term;
    }
    printf("Sum is: %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on Linux, so I removed the header `<conio.h>` which is non-standard.

Comment: @haccks I don't know what you mean ;) Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass **address** to `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Also, your `for` loop is invalid. Condition `i-(2*n-1)` never changes because `i` and `n` never change.

Answer (score 1):

scanf is written wrongly.

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

Also, loop is going infinitely.